# scipy basinhopping accept_test: what is f_new and f_old

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to optimize an antenna placement and orientation problem using simulated annealing. I believe scipy.basinhopping would do what I need but I don't understand the meaning of f_new and f_old in the accept_test function. I don't see an explanation in the documentation. If anybody could enlighten me on the meaning of those kwargs that would be great. The specific callable that I am confused about is:

```
 accept_test : callable, accept_test(f_new=f_new, x_new=x_new, f_old=fold, x_old=x_old), optional
```

Thank you,

Ranga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html#scipy-optimize-basinhopping

```
accept_test : callable, ``accept_test(f_new=f_new, x_new=x_new, f_old=fold, x_old=x_old)``, optional
    Define a test which will be used to judge whether or not to accept the
    step.  This will be used in addition to the Metropolis test based on
    "temperature" ``T``.  The acceptable return values are True,
    False, or ``"force accept"``. If any of the tests return False
    then the step is rejected. If the latter, then this will override any
    other tests in order to accept the step. This can be used, for example,
    to forcefully escape from a local minimum that ``basinhopping`` is
    trapped in.
```

The information that you can collect from this is, calling the argument `a`:

1. `a` is a callable, you can thus provide a function.
2. `a` acts as in the decision for the evolution algorithm. The possible return values are True and False, that are used in combination with the Metropolis condition (i.e. the two criteria must return True for the step to be accepted), and "force accept". The latter option must be used when you want to force acceptance in situations where Metropolis would reject.
3. You can use the values of the current step `x_old` and `f_old` (these are values here, not callables) and of the new step `x_new` and `f_new` in your custom criterion.

Below, I set up a toy example where the accept_test function forces acceptance when the step is to the right in *parameter space*

```
def f(x):
    return x**2

def a(f_new, x_new, f_old, x_old):
    if x_new>x_old:
        return "force accept"
    else:
        return True

basinhopping(f, 1, accept_test=a)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but I still don't understand f_old and f_new based on your explanation. Would it be possible to modify your example to use f_old and f_new.

Comment: `f_old` and `f_new` are the values of the energy function before and after the *proposed* update from `x_old` to `x_new`. For a plain statistical physics system, this the old energy `e_old` and the new energy `e_new` in the Metropolis criterion `exp(-(e_old-e_new)/(k_B*T))`